# Library wkhtmltopdf is not working inside Docker

Tags: docker, flask, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I have a code in Python Flask where I generate pdf files using an HTML template. The code works just fine when I run it alone, but when I try to run it inside a Docker container, as soon as I call the endpoint that generates the report the docker crashes and resets. It just stays loading then it returns an error (in Postman which I'm using to test).

The code for the PDF is as follows:

```
def create_report(download_uuid):
    transactions = get_transaction_for_report(download_uuid)
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=environ.get('WKHTMLTOPDF'))

    file_obj = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(file_obj, 'w') as zip_file:
        for transaction in transactions:
            html = render_template("report.html", transaction=transaction)
            pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config)
            data = zipfile.ZipInfo('{}.pdf'.format(transaction['control_number']))
            data.compress_type = zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED
            zip_file.writestr(data, pdf)
    file_obj.seek(0)
    return send_file(file_obj, attachment_filename="forms.zip", as_attachment=True)
```

It is returning a zip file, but inside the zip file are pdf files. Furthermore, if I remove the pdf generating part, the zip file returns just fine. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM madnight/docker-alpine-wkhtmltopdf as wkhtmltopdf_image
FROM python:3.9-alpine

RUN adduser -D custom

WORKDIR /home/Project

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv venv
RUN venv/bin/pip install --upgrade pip
RUN apk add make automake gcc g++ subversion python3-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev libffi-dev musl-dev openssl-dev freetype freetype-dev ttf-freefont libxrender qt5-qtbase-dev
RUN venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN venv/bin/pip install gunicorn

COPY Project Project
COPY boot.sh app.py .env run.py create_database.py config.py ./
COPY templates templates
COPY static static
COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf_image /bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
RUN chmod +x boot.sh

ENV FLASK_APP app.py

USER root
RUN chown -R custom ./
USER custom

EXPOSE 9001
ENTRYPOINT ["./boot.sh"]
```

I should say that this is the last iteration of many, MANY attempts to try to get this to work. Essentially, I've tried getting wkhtmltox by curl, I've tried putting wkhtmltopdf in different directories. So far nothing has worked. I don't know what I'm missing. This is basically what I need to fix in order to finish this project so any help at all will be immensely appreciated.

EDIT: docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    networks:
      - custom
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - "./static:/home/EventismedEquipmentAPI/static"
    external_links:
      - eventismed-equipment:db
networks:
  custom:
    external: true
```

Comment: What is the output of `docker logs [your_container_name]` ?

Comment: `app_1 | [2021-04-27 13:32:24 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:23)

app_1 | [2021-04-27 09:32:24 -0400] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)

app_1 | [2021-04-27 13:32:24 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24`

That, then it restarts.

Comment: Any more info you need? Please I'm kinda desperate to solve this.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/cornernote/09221c5896d36133c3f36ecc13c928aa shows a way to use wkhtmltopdf in docker. Study and try to apply it to your project. There are several pieces of data in your question that are missing, but I think you can do this first.

Comment: So @plasmy did you make it ?

Comment: No. Right now what I'm trying is creating a container which only has wkhtmltopdf, and calling it from my other container to see if it works. I wanted to do it all in one container but absolutely nothing I tried worked.

Comment: Did you try the link I sent you ?

Comment: @Niloct yes I did.

Comment: Are you running docker on windows ?

Comment: Sorry the Dockerfile on that link is broken. I am looking into it now.

Comment: I am running on Mac. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Good, I am too. Will update you.

Comment: I've managed to isolate working wkhtmltopdf, see answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's fix this.

I've managed to run `wkhtmltopdf` isolated on a docker container.

Dockerfile:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737156/152016
# Create image based on the official openjdk 8-jre-alpine image from the dockerhub
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# Install wkhtmltopdf
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925361/152016
RUN apk add --no-cache wkhtmltopdf ttf-dejavu

ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  wkhtmltopdf:
    image: wkhtmltopdf
    container_name: wkhtmltopdf
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
```

Then:

```
docker-compose build
docker run -ti --rm -v /tmp:/tmp wkhtmltopdf
```

Inside the container:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wkhtmltopdf https://www.google.com test.pdf
```

Then you will see the pdf on your mac at `/tmp/test.pdf`

First let me know if this works.

Comment: Yes, this worked perfectly :) But is there any way I can integrate this with my project?

Comment: Your python docker image is running on alpine too. So you can just get rid of the first `FROM` and the `COPY --from=wkhtmltopdf`, and add the 2 packages `wkhtmltopdf ttf-dejavu` on your original `RUN apk add`, change entrypoint to `ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]` to test, then run the `docker run` command I told you, and generate another pdf inside the new image to test isolated pdf creation.

Comment: So I tried this and I got the following:
`QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-eventismed'
Loading page (1/2)
Error compiling builtin:                                     ] 30%
Fatal error compiling builtin function 'apply': Segmentation fault`

I also have a docker-compose file I use, I'll edit it to the main question

Comment: Also I should add, I tried changing the `ENTRYPOINT` like you said, but the project was not running for some reason so I had to change it to how I have it.

Comment: Read about `ENTRYPOINT`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint basically it's the command your container runs on start. I changed it to `sh` so when you do a docker run, it will start a shell inside the container and you can repeat the last commands to see if wkhtmltopdf is running ok. Then you change entrypoint back to `./boot.sh`.

Comment: Good morning @plasmy. Let me know if you don't understand the last comment.

Comment: Good morning @Niloct. First, I would like to thank you for everything you've helped me with. I stayed up until late last night, and I managed to fix it. The problem was never WKHTML, it was the html file I was using. For some reason, any reference I had to static images or files was causing the process to crash. I was using the standard way in jinja2, by using the `url_for`. I had to change that up and everything worked like a charm. I can't believe it took me so long to figure this out. But I am very grateful for your help and for following up.

Comment: Congratulations @plasmy! You can add details in a response, and mark it as an answer here. If you feel good about it.

Comment: I do. I am very grateful to you @Niloct. Very rarely do I find people as helpful as you in this website. Hopefully we can coincide some other time. You seem like someone I could learn a lot from.

Comment: You're very polite, thanks! Actually I don't think I've expressed myself, I meant you could add an answer yourself and mark that as the accepted answer, not my try. You can mark me here or shout me at my e-mail anytime :)

Comment: @Niloct thanks for you answer its woking fine. I have another scenario how to convert html to pdf by using above approch ?