# Using library pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf inside Docker container for Flask app

Tags: python, docker, flask, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I am creating a Flask app that uses the library PDFkit to generate a PDF file from a HTML string. When running the code locally it works fine, however when I try to run it inside a Docker container this error comes up:

`OSError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found: "C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe"`

The function used to generate the pdf is given below:

```
def generate_pdf_schedule(schedules):
    html_string = schedule_to_html_string(schedules)

    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe')

    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html_string, configuration=config)

    return pdf
```

Inside this function the html_string needs to be converted to a PDF file, when this is running it generates the above mentioned error.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:latest

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


WORKDIR /app
```

I am using a docker-compose.yml as I have several containers running at once, my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
  web:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: app
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: flask run -h 0.0.0.0
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
  celery:
    build:
        context: .
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: app
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    command: celery -A app.celery worker --loglevel=info
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

I am really new to Docker and programming in general, couldn't figure this out on my own. I have tried several answers on questions that are alike to this one. The biggest issue seems to be adjusting the answers in such a way that it suits my project.

Some things I found in other questions that I have tried:
Adding this to my Dockerfile

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/62737156/152016
# Create image based on the official openjdk 8-jre-alpine image from the dockerhub
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# Install wkhtmltopdf
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/56925361/152016
RUN apk add --no-cache wkhtmltopdf ttf-dejavu

ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
```

And this to my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  wkhtmltopdf:
    image: wkhtmltopdf
    container_name: wkhtmltopdf
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
```

However it seems to not work if I pull both

`FROM python:latest`
`FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine`

this results in either pip not being found or apk not being found.

How can I integrate pdfkit/wkhtmltopdf to my project?

Answer (score 1):

`C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe` is for Windows and won't exist in a Linux Docker container.

So you'll need to adjust the path to where `wkhtmltopdf` is installed in the container.

```
def generate_pdf_schedule(schedules):
    html_string = schedule_to_html_string(schedules)

    # Adjust the path for wkhtmltopdf based on its location in the Alpine container
    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf')

    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html_string, configuration=config)

    return pdf
```

Also update the docker file to reference the docker image that supports `pip` and `apk`.

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache wkhtmltopdf ttf-dejavu
COPY requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r /app/requirements.txt

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /app
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. This does seem to work in some sense, as both `apk` and `pip` are running.

However I do receive a new error:
`0.797 ERROR: unable to select packages: `
`wkhtmltopdf (no such package):`
`required by: world[wkhtmltopdf]`

I tried changing the alpine version to `python:3.8-alpine3.14` (as that was something I found in a different question) however this seems to break pip, as it gives a lot of errors at that point. 

Any clue on how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe you need to add testing repository to the `apk`
`RUN echo "@testing http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main" >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN echo "@testing http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community" >> /etc/apk/repositories`
You can change the version

Comment: It is saying `ERROR: unable to select packages:` `wkhtmltopdf-0.12.5-r1:` `masked in: @testing`, it does this for other libraries as well (`qt5-qtwebkit-5.212.0_alpha4-r11`, `qt5-qtbase-5.14.2-r1`, `icu-libs-67.1-r0`)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer other people encountering this problem are searching for since it no longer uses pdfkit.

I accomplished my goal on a different way. Decided to no longer use pdfkit and started using weasyprint (in my case I used flask_weasyprint since I am running a flask app, but weasyprint should be fine for other cases).

Function to generate pdf file from HTML string:

```
from weasyprint import HTML


def makepdf(html):
    """Generate a PDF file from a string of HTML."""
    htmldoc = HTML(string=html, base_url="")
    return htmldoc.write_pdf()
```